# Will I lose desktop files if I restore Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I can't get my laptop to start.  I have tried all the diagnostics with no results.  I think my only option may be to reinstall Windows 10.  I know there is an option that will allow me to save my personal files when reinstalling, but was wondering if my files that I have saved on my desktop will also be saved.  I'm not worried about programs, I will just have to go through the irritation of reinstalling those, but I have a couple folders on my desktop that I really don't want to lose.

Comment: Also, am I going to need anything to reinstall Windows 10.  My computer came with it already loaded.  I don't have any disks, and did not make any restore disks.

Comment: The only option you will be given, if you boot to the installation environment, is to perform a clean install

Answer (score 0):

The desktop is part of your "personal area" so it should be kept. But you shouldn't have saved files in your desktop anyway, at least nothing of importance (Gnome based Linux distros soon will no longer allow it).

However, depending on the actual damage that's preventing booting, it may not be possible to salvage your files, no matter where they are.

**We do backups regularly to avoid those situations from the get go.**

Recovering files from a damaged drive / file system is always a time consuming task with absolutely no guarantees of success. And to make things worse, if you haven't disabled the Windows Fast Startup feature before the problem, it'll be very hard to mount the drive in a Linux live session, the "tool" many people use to backup personal files from an unbootable Windows partition. Also encryption like BitLocker can make it almost impossible to recover.

On the bright side, reinstalling Windows nowadays is easier than it used to be and you can download the installer [directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Of course, reinstalling in this way requires installation of all the required drivers as well. The drivers should be provided by the manufacturer, not Microsoft. Reinstalling with the recovery media that you should have made in day one would restore the factory image including all the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *guarantee* that all files can be saved during a major procedure such as reinstallation of OS, though it's *likely* they'll survive. If you've not yet made a backup of of your files, it's not too late to do now, if the HDD still operates. Either of these should work:

- Make a rescue disk or USB drive on another PC, using Windows PE ([Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and other backup software and many antiviruses will do that for you) or a Linux distro such as [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)). Boot from rescue media, mount the computer's HDD (read-only is OK), and copy your files to the flash drive or to anther device.
- Open the PC, remove the HDD and mount it on another PC, either in an existing drive slot or in [an external HDD enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OJ3UJ2S). Copy the files to the other PC.

After you've rescued what you need, it's then safe to reinstall Windows, with your choice of trying to keep old files or not.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speak, if you use Repair install with saving all your files, files on desktop will not lose.

But, to avoid unexpectedly issue, I recommend you create a WinPE USB, and copy out your desktop files for backup.

Create PE USB:

https://4sysops.com/archives/build-a-bootable-windows-pe-3-0-usb-drive-with-rescue-tools-part-1/

Use copy or robocopy commands to copy out the files under c:\users\username\desktop